# Has anyone else had problems with a Stages power meter at high cadence?

Tags: power, cadence

I just started using a stages power meter and it works as expected but with one major flaw so far.  When I just did some sprint intervals on the trainer as soon as the cadence went above 150 rpm the cadence read 0 for one refresh,  the power froze for 2 or 3 refresh cycles and then also read 0 until i finished the interval.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I don't have a power meter, but does this occur every time you exceed 150 rpm?

Comment: 150 is a lot though, it wouldn't surprise me if they wrote the software with some kind of failsafe which at those levels assumes the sensor is kaput. Do Stages have an online forum? When I've tried to discover the nuances of how my Garmin works, the most productive place has always been the forum.

Comment: It uses an accelerometer to infer crank position and cadence, and so I wouldn't be surprised if it has trouble discerning crank position from the noise as pedal speeds increase.

Comment: I've had similar issues with my Powertap C1.  When cadence gets too high (probably about the same), it outputs go unstable:  cadence might read zero, it might read 40, power is all over the place and too low.  When I need to do high-cadence workouts, I pull out the old race bike that still has its SRM power meter, with its magnet-based cadence sensor.